# Stackoverflow error while unmarshling in JBoss Client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, marshalling

I am getting unmarshling error in one of the swing screen while receiving data from JBoss application server (EAP 6.4.2-1). I am using JDK 1.8.

Following Libraries are in client class path:

```
jboss-client.jar
picketbox-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar
javaee-api-6.0.jar
jboss-ejb3-ext-api-2.1.0.redhat-1.jar
```

This error never comes if i run application from Eclipse 4.4 J2EE environment. 
Please help.

Stack Trace is:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.jboss.marshalling.UTFUtils.readUTFBytes(UTFUtils.java:146)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:180)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:776)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:180)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:776)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:180)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:776)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:180)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:776)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)

        org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)

        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:661)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
......
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(RiverObjectInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1637)
......
```

Comment: How big is object you try to unmarshall?

Comment: it has list of around 100 plus objects and each object size is 300 to 400 kb